# Return data from textfields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-ajax

I have a view with some text fields, the view looks like this:

```
 @model SDB.Models.EmailTemplate.EmailTemplateModel

@{
    AutorisatieModel autorisatieModel = ViewBag.AutorisatieModel;
    bool heeftSchrijfrechten = autorisatieModel.BeheerEmailTemplatesSchrijven;
}

<div class="panel panel-default basisViewEdit">

    <div class="panel-heading">
        Email template
    </div>
    <p class="three">
        Op deze pagina kun je de mail die aan nieuw personeel wordt verzonden aanpassen naar je eigen smaak.
        <br /> Pas de content aan en bekijk de preview van de mail voor het te verwachten resultaat.
    </p>


    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>

            @using (Html.BeginForm("Wijzigen", "EmailTemplate", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "EmailTemplateOpslaan" }))
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)

                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-horizontal col-md-12">
                        @FormGroupHelper.CreateFormGroup(Html, m => m.Afzender, heeftSchrijfrechten)
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-horizontal col-md-12">
                        @FormGroupHelper.CreateFormGroup(Html, m => m.Onderwerp, heeftSchrijfrechten)
                    </div>

                    @if (Html.GebruikerContext().Klant.LogoIDSpecified)
                    {


                        <div class="form-horizontal col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-2">
                                    <label for="Titel">Logo</label>
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 73px;">
                                    <div style="height: 73px; padding: 1px; border: 1px solid #eee;">
                                        <img src='/Beheer/images/sdbayton.png' />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class='col-md-4' style="height: 73px;">
                                    <div style="height: 73px; padding: 1px; border: 1px solid #eee;">
                                        <img src='/Beheer/Document/Download?documentID=@(Html.GebruikerContext().Klant.LogoID)' />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                                    @Html.RadioButton("logo-selectie", "standaard", !Model.GebruikKlantLogo, new { @name = "logoKeuze" })
                                    @Html.Label("standaard logo")
                                </div>
                                <div class='col-md-4'>
                                    @Html.RadioButton("logo-selectie", "klant", Model.GebruikKlantLogo, new { @name = "logoKeuze" })
                                    @Html.Label("eigen logo")
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }

                    <div class="form-horizontal col-md-12">
                        @FormGroupHelper.CreateFormGroup(Html, m => m.Titel, heeftSchrijfrechten)
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-horizontal col-md-12">
                        @FormGroupHelper.CreateFormGroup(Html, m => m.IntroductieTekst, "TekstAreaTemplate", heeftSchrijfrechten)
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-horizontal col-md-12">
                        @FormGroupHelper.CreateFormGroup(Html, m => m.AfzenderTekst, "TekstAreaTemplate", heeftSchrijfrechten)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">

                </div>
            }

            @FormGroupHelper.CreateFormGroup(Html, m => m.Afzender, heeftSchrijfrechten)

            <th>

                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform">
                    @FormGroupHelper.CreateFormGroup(Html, m => m.Afzender, heeftSchrijfrechten)
                </textarea>
            </th>
        </tr>

    </table>

    @if (heeftSchrijfrechten)
    {
        <div class="panel-footer"></div>

        <div class="navigatie alignRight">
            @ButtonHelper.Button(ButtonType.Default, ButtonSize.Large, "Annuleren", id: "annuleren", icon: "glyphicon-arrow-left", href: Url.Action("../EmailTemplate"))
            @*@ButtonHelper.Button(ButtonType.Default, ButtonSize.Large, Messages.Global_Action_Annuleren, "stap-verwijderen", icon: "glyphicon-remove")*@
            @ButtonHelper.Button(ButtonType.Primary, ButtonSize.Large, Messages.Global_Action_Opslaan, "opslaan")
            @ButtonHelper.Button(ButtonType.Primary, ButtonSize.Large, Messages.Global_Action_previewEmail, "PreviewEmail")
        </div>
    }
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#opslaan').click(function () {
            $('#EmailTemplateOpslaan').submit();
        });





        $('#PreviewEmail').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: '@Url.Action("PreviewEmail", "EmailTemplate", new { area = "Salaris"})',
                //data: { EmailContent: "value" },
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                //dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {

                }
            });

        });


    });
</script>
```

and I have a textarea in the view like this:

And the model looks like this:

```
public class EmailTemplateModel : IValidatableObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Afzender { get; set; }

        public string Onderwerp { get; set; }

        public bool GebruikKlantLogo { get; set; }

        public string Titel { get; set; }

        public string IntroductieTekst { get; set; }

        public string AfzenderTekst { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Titel))
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Onderwerp moet gevuld zijn.", new List<string>() { "Titel" });
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(IntroductieTekst))
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Inhoud moet gevuld zijn.", new List<string>() { "Inhoud" });
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I want if you put some data in the textfields, for example:
for the property:

```
   @FormGroupHelper.CreateFormGroup(Html, m => m.Afzender, heeftSchrijfrechten)
```

I fill in: Albert Newton.

Then I want with the button in the view. The button looks like this:

```
 @ButtonHelper.Button(ButtonType.Primary, ButtonSize.Large, Messages.Global_Action_previewEmail, "PreviewEmail")
```

And I have a ajax call in the view like this:

```
$('#PreviewEmail').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: '@Url.Action("PreviewEmail", "EmailTemplate", new { area = "Salaris"})',
                //data: { EmailContent: "value" },
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                //dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {

                }
            });

        });
```

and the ajax method calls this method:

```
  [HttpGet]
        [AutorisatieFilter(Rol = "Beheer | Email templates@Lezen")]
        public ActionResult PreviewEmail()
        {
            EmailTemplateModel model = new EmailTemplateModel();
           string test = null;

            if (model != null)
            {  

            }      

            return View(model); // viewname is your cshtml file name
        }
```

That the properties of the model appear in the textarea in the view.

So my queststion is How to return the data that you fill in in the model properties appear in the textarea?

Thank you

Comment: instead of returning a view result, return the string data you want to display in the text area and use `$("#yourTextAreaId").val(resultFromAjaxCall);`

Comment: Thank you. But what I have to put in the action method PreviewEmail?

Comment: `return Content(model.TheStringPropertyWhichHasEmailBody)`

Comment: But oke. It is not one model property. there are five model properties and all the model properties I want to have in the textarea

Comment: Well, it should be, else way you can retrieve it in the code behind

Comment: Can you give an example? Thank you

Comment: Because every time I look in the action method, model is not null, but the properties of the model are always empty.

Comment: I also had this problem once, the question you have to ask yourself is : Why are my model properties returned null even when I filled them with info in the view before posting. A question to which no one can answer except by looking at your whole code.

Comment: You have those input element values client side, you can show that in any DOM element

Comment: Yes oke, but  do you have an example?

Comment: just read the values using jQuery selectors and set to the target element

Comment: Sorry, but can you give an example. will be nice. I don't understand